# Java Google Gmail API Read All Messages

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

So far I've been able to go through all the emails in one of my accounts and print out the message snippets, but I want to be able to print out the full message.

Here is the code I'm using so far.

```
public static void getEmails() {
        try {
            ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list("me").execute();

            List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            while (response.getMessages() != null) {
                messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
                if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                    String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                    response = service.users().messages().list("me").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (Message message : messages) {
                System.out.println(message.getId());
                Message test = service.users().messages().get("me", message.getId()).execute();
                System.out.println(test.getSnippet());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I print out the full content of the message in plain text? (not raw formatted or anything).

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering what the answer is to this you just have to add this code.

```
Message test = service.users().messages().get("me", message.getId()).setFormat("full").execute();
                System.out.println(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(test.getPayload().getBody().getData())));
```

That will give you html code to work with, where you can extract the things you need. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To read the body part, you need to extract it from the returned JSON object and then decode:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

//Code from the post

System.out.println(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(test.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData())));
```

Comment: It's difficult to see any difference, except the `.get(0)` which had not been explained - when comparing this to the 7 years old answer right above. And since variable `test` is not even defined, it's probably useless.